# Usage of input:hidden selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Let's say we have two `div` with `display:none` style attribute like this :

```
<div id="dv_1" style="display:none;">
    DIV - 1
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="dv_1_radio_gender" value="male" checked="checked" /> Male
    <input type="radio" name="dv_1_radio_gender" value="female" /> Female
    <input type="hidden" name="dv_1_radio_gender" value="male" />
</div>

<div id="dv_2" style="display:none;">
    DIV - 2
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="dv_2_radio_gender" value="male" checked="checked" /> Male
    <input type="radio" name="dv_2_radio_gender" value="female" /> Female
    <input type="hidden" name="dv_2_radio_gender" value="male" />
</div>
```

As you can see, each `div` contains two radio buttons and one hidden `input` field.

If we try to set new value to hidden field like this :

```
$('input:hidden[name="dv_1_radio_gender"]').val('female');
```

The selector seems get all elements that has the same name inside a hidden (`display: none`) `div` and set value to `'female'`.

if we change `div` with this first :

```
$(div).show();
```

Еhen everything works perfectly.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/3jwoLvae/1/).

So, here is my question: why does selector get all matched elements in a hidden `div`? Doesn't the syntax `$('input:hidden[name="xxx"]')` means to find `input` which is a `hidden` type?

Comment: I don't know what might be the problem but I've checked your code and it works like how you wanted it to be..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) for `:hidden` selector:

*Selects all elements that are hidden.*

*Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:*

1. They have a CSS display value of none.
2. They are form elements with type="hidden".
3. Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
4. An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Number 4 is what is all about: all `<input>`s are inside hidden `<div>`s. To select only `<input>` with type `hidden`, you can use `input[type="hidden"]`.

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/3jwoLvae/2/).

Answer (score 0):

This will select all inputs with name "dv_1_radio_gender" that are not visible, no matter what kind of inputs they are:

```
$('input:hidden[name="dv_1_radio_gender"]');
```

This second one will select all inputs of type hidden with name "dv_1_radio_gender", no matter if they are inside a hidden parent element or not:

```
$('input[type="hidden][name="dv_1_radio_gender"]');
```